# List QTable - Select Dynamic

Tags: c++, qt4, qt-creator

Good afternoon

I have a question.

I'm not getting the data in Qtable list.

And is not showing any errors.

My code:

```
#include <QtSql>
#include "listuser.h"
#include "conex.h"


my_listuser::my_listuser(QDialog *parent)
{
   setupUi(this); // this sets up GUI
   connect(pushButton_list, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(list_user()));

}


void my_listuser::list_user()
{
         int i=0;

         conex();
         colum_horzHeaders();

         QSqlQuery query;
         query.exec("SELECT name_user FROM user");

         while(query.next()) {
             QString name_user = query.value(0).toString();
             tableWidget->setRowCount(i);
             QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem(QString("%1").arg(name_user));
             tableWidget->setItem(i,0,item);
             i++;
         }
}

void my_listuser::colum_horzHeaders()
{
    tableWidget->setColumnCount(1);
    QStringList horzHeaders;
    horzHeaders << "Name";
    tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horzHeaders);
}
```

I think the error is here...

```
 while(query.next()) {
     QString name_user = query.value(0).toString();
     tableWidget->setRowCount(i);
     QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem(QString("%1").arg(name_user));
     tableWidget->setItem(i,0,item);
     i++;
 }
```

I would be very grateful for the help. Thank you.

Comment: What is broken? What are you expecting us to fix? We don't have a magic wand to know that unless you tell us.Are you at Hogwarts by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
tableWidget->setRowCount(i+1);
```

If you are accessing `i`th row, then row count must be at least `i+1`, as rows indexd are zero-based.